# How to simulate the save as of a webpage in google chrome using an extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

One of the things that my extension needs to do is to save the current page to the user's hard drive just like the user would do if he clicks on ctrl + s and save it and return the full path of the file (like "c:\some folder\google.html").

I could not find a way to do it, anyone knows a way?

Thanks

Comment: See http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageCapture.html